# Poner límite en el tiempo de ejecución en las iteraciones de un bucle en R

Tags: r

Quiero limitar el tiempo de ejecución de las iteraciones dentro de un bucle *sapply* y que en caso de que el ordenador exceda ese tiempo límite ignore la iteración actual y pase a la siguiente. He estado buscando comandos que usar en la versión *3.3.2*, pero no encuentro ninguno.

Por si sirve de algo, dejo aquí mi código, aunque usa funciones que he definido en otros scripts:

```
XYresult <- function(binbox,numb){

    mat<- sapply(X = numb, function(x){

            print(x)
            B <- newvoxel(read.table(file = paste("/Users/entimos/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Quinto/Data/Event_",x,".dat",sep ="")),binbox)
            B <- B[,1:2]
            Xlim <- c(min(B[,1])-1, max(B[,1])+1);  Ylim <- c(min(B[,2])-1, max(B[,2])+1); by <-0.1
            Xseq <- seq(Xlim[1], Xlim[2], by = by)
            Yseq <- seq(Ylim[1], Ylim[2], by = by)
            Grid <- expand.grid(Xseq, Yseq)

            h <- 0.2
            band <- bootstrapBand(X = B[,1:2], FUN = dtm, Grid = Grid, B = 100,
                                  parallel = T, alpha = 0.1, m0 = h) 

            Diag <- gridDiag(X = B[,1:2], FUN = dtm, m0 = h, lim = cbind(Xlim, Ylim),
                             by = by, sublevel = FALSE, library = "Dionysus",
                             printProgress = T)

            feature <- getfeature(Diag[["diagram"]], 2*band[["width"]])
            c(x, sum(feature[,1]==0), sum(feature[,1]==1))
    })

    mat <- t(mat)
    colnames(mat) <- c("id", "betti0", "betti1")
    mat <-  data.frame(mat)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un ejemplo de algo que podrías implementar usando [`withTimeout`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.5.0/topics/withTimeout)

```
require(R.utils)

mi.funcion <- function(x)
{
    Sys.sleep(1*x) 
    return(x^x)
}

mi.funcion.with.tiemout <- function(x, timeout=1)
{
    # En caso de timeout, no genero error y devuelvo -1
    ret <- withTimeout(mi.funcion(x), timeout = timeout, onTimeout = "silent")
    if (is.null(ret)) {ret = -1}
    return(ret)
}

sapply(c(1,2,3,4), mi.funcion.with.tiemout, timeout=4)
```

El retorno:

```
[1]  1  4 27 -1
```

Como vez al llegar al valor 4 se supera el timeout y se aplica en este caso un valor genérico -1 que devuelve la función propia `mi.funcion.with.tiemout`